# What effect does defining a non-const inline static member have on compilation?

Tags: c++, static, c++17, inline

Since C++17, we can declare any static member "inline", even if it is not const:

```
class Foo
{
    static inline std::vector<int>;
};
```

Of course, the standard doesn't say much on the effect on the process of compilation. So I was wondering, in terms of just how the program is compiled, does "inline static" have any downsides VS defining it separately (most of the time inside the .cpp)? Or is it just safe to replace any and all static-variables with the inline-variant?

The one difference I can see is that having the definition in the cpp allows me to change the default-value w/o recompiling all dependencies of the header; but I rarely assign a non-default value to static members.

Comment: If you are asking how this is typically implemented - same as global inline variables and inline functions. The definition is emitted in every translation unit that odr-uses the variable, with instructions to the linker to pick one copy and discard all others.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, that is basically my question. So that means that, in terms of efficiency/compile-time, this has a potential overhead by the compiler having to create the definition in all those translation-units; compared to placing the definition in the one translation-unit by hand - correct?

Comment: Yes, it has some compile-time overhead; probably insignificant. It shouldn't add any overhead to the resulting binary.

Comment: I wonder if it might have an interesting interaction with symbol visibility?